# Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

I'm trying to return a value from an API function with dataTask. When editing the code, I get the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

I added the code below. Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm new to Swift.

```swift
func getNonce() {
    let headers = [
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    ]
    let parameters = [
      "id": 1,
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "params": [addressETH, "pending"],
      "method": "eth_getTransactionCount"
    ] as [String : Any]
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/myapikeygoeshere")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData! as Data
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> String in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error as Any)
        } else {
            let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
            let start = dataString.index(dataString.startIndex, offsetBy: 36)
            let end = dataString.index(dataString.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
            let range = start..<end
            let user_Nonce = String(dataString[range])
            return user_Nonce?
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

The error is on this line:

```swift
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> String in
```

I tried to return the value but the error popped up.

Comment: There are a lot of problems here, but starting with the error in your image... The URLSession method you're using has a completion handler of type `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void` but you've replaced it with `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> String`, which won't work. In addition you only sometimes return a `String` in your implementation, so you'd need to add a `return nil` in your first `if` branch, and would need the closure to then be a `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> String?` which again still wouldn't work because that's not what the signature of that method takes.

Comment: The question is also ambiguous.  Add the detail directly to the question, not as a photo, to make it easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on how completion handlers or async await work in swift. Here are some examples on how you could structure this function to work - and you'll have to account for the completion handler or async await at the call site. There are also a fair number of force unwraps (`!`) in here, which you should avoid, same with `try?`. Catch those conditions and report the errors to the caller.

```
// Example using closures

func getNonce(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
    let headers = [
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    ]
    
    let parameters = [
      "id": 1,
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "params": ["addressETH", "pending"],
      "method": "eth_getTransactionCount"
    ] as [String : Any]
    
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/myapikeygoeshere")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData!
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
            let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
            let start = dataString.index(dataString.startIndex, offsetBy: 36)
            let end = dataString.index(dataString.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
            let range = start..<end
            let user_Nonce = String(dataString[range])
            completion(.success(user_Nonce))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

// Example using async await

func getNonce() async throws -> String {
    let headers = [
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    ]
    
    let parameters = [
      "id": 1,
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "params": ["addressETH", "pending"],
      "method": "eth_getTransactionCount"
    ] as [String : Any]
    
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/myapikeygoeshere")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData!
    
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    let start = dataString.index(dataString.startIndex, offsetBy: 36)
    let end = dataString.index(dataString.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
    let range = start..<end
    let user_Nonce = String(dataString[range])

    return user_Nonce
}

// Assuming called from viewDidLoad in a view controller

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // How to call using closure example
    
    getNonce { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let nonce):
            print("got nonce: \(nonce)")
            
        case .failure(let error):
            // handle error
            break
        }
    }
    
    // How to call using async await example
    Task {
        do {
            let nonce = try await getNonce()
            print("got nonce: \(nonce)")
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast and clear response. I tried it and it works! But how would I assign the nonce to a global variable? I need to return the nonce value in another function, to use it as a parameter. When I assign it to an existing global variable, the global variable prints as a blank string (doesn't assign the nonce value to it).

Comment: Depending on where it's used you could store it in different places. For example if you had a root view controller, you could get it there, then pass it to further presented view controllers as a dependency. If it's something used widely it may make sense to store it in a common place it's used, say a user manager class or api class. This is where singletons vs baton passing / dependency injection concerns start to pop up!

Comment: Also, if this helped / worked, please accept / upvote the answer :)

Comment: Accepted the answer :). Sorry for these nooby questions I’m pretty new as u can tell lol. But if you can further explain how I can set the nonce value to a global variable, that would be amazing :)

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty example that ignores a bunch of possible failure states https://gist.github.com/andrewroycarter/0aa91b8092784c285a5c6f6e980866f1

Comment: One more quick and LESS dirty example, assuming the nonce is to be used to make API calls, you could cache the nonce in the instance of the API class, and only fetch it if / when needed. https://gist.github.com/andrewroycarter/7a2b4cb28cfca924bc0e001ad03d8874

Comment: But overall you should read up on dependency management in swift. There are MANY options and strategies, and reaching for singletons / shared instances may seem quick and easy but there are lots of downsides. Sometimes it is the right answer though. Make sure your solution is fairly unopinionated and decoupled, making it easy to refactor if / when it needs to be expanded or refactored. Also, try to not reach for any third party libraries to do this. Swift / the iOS SDK contain many tools to solve these problems, and the better you understand the first party solutions the better off you'll be!

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I'll look these up and apply what you gave me. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: I was able to find a solution with your guidance. Thanks!